# Periodically backup a Postgres database using cron in Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I would like to periodically backup a Postgres database. I am using Docker Compose, here is the snippet of the Postgres container:

```
  postgres:
    build: ./compose/postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - postgres_backup:/backups
```

And the Postgres dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:9.6

# add backup scripts
ADD backup.sh /usr/local/bin/backup
ADD restore.sh /usr/local/bin/restore
ADD list-backups.sh /usr/local/bin/list-backups

# make them executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/restore
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/list-backups
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/backup
```

I would like to add a cron task (say `backup-cron`) that runs `backup.sh` **every day at midnight**.

I have read this [tutorial](https://www.ekito.fr/people/run-a-cron-job-with-docker/) but I do not know how to properly integrate it. Any help?